# Excel: Insert query throws error message "Operation must use an updateable query"

Tags: c#, excel, vba, oledb, oledbconnection

I am running into an error when trying to insert into an Excel worksheet

This is the layout of my Excel worksheet named Sheet1:

```
     id    name
     1     test 
     2     apple
     3     pear
```

I want to insert this data into the Excel worksheet:

```
     4     pineapple
```

This is my code below:

```
try{
            string srcExcel = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\insertTest.xlsx";
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection;
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand myCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
            string sql = null;
            MyConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = " + srcExcel + "; Extended Properties = 'Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1'");
            MyConnection.Open();
            myCommand.Connection = MyConnection;
            sql = "Insert Into [Sheet1$] (id,name) Values('4','pineapple')";
            myCommand.CommandText = sql;
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Insert Success!");
            MyConnection.Close();
}
        catch (Exception eInnerData)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Method: getInnerData " + eInnerData.ToString());
        }
```

After running this code an exception is thrown and caught with this error message:

> Operation must use an updateable query

I am using Microsoft Excel 2010

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the IMEX=1 from the connectionstring. Also make sure the file is not readonly and not currently open in Excel

For what it's worth, I recommend reading and writing the xlsx file with something like the EPPlus library, rather than the Access db driver

Comment: Plus 1 for using EPPlus. Using Oledb requires installation of drivers on 64-bit client computers and and the behavior is very unpredictable and error prone.

Comment: After removing IMEX=1, the error still persists, and for using EPPlus I have never used it before, can you recommend where to start? I have installed EPPlus through NuGet Manager

Comment: Something like this would be a good starting point: https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki/Getting-Started (it's the wiki/tutorial for eppluss, written by the author of epplus)

Comment: I think I found the issue, I was able to insert data using epplus, but when I was looking at the original issue, I believe the issue arises because I am reading data from the Excel file to do certain tasks, then once completed write back to that excel file. I think the error occurs because  the Excel file is still open or being read from and can't be updated or inserted into while that happens. Would you know of a work around?

Comment: Doesn't seem logical if you used the access driver to do both readi and writing, and didn't have multiple connections open to it.. you're free to do as you wish with your code, but access driver is a shortcut to headaches

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when an access database or excel document is stored in folder were you do not have write write access. You can read the file but you wont be able to make changes to it.

Please ensure you have access to this folder or run your program as an administrator.

You can confirm the write permissions on Windows by checking that you have access under the security tab on file properties.

[image]

Comment: For the User, they have full Modify and Write permission and the error still occurs